# How to unit test an apache camel cxfrs route?

Tags: json, unit-testing, apache-camel, cxfrs

I have a working cxfrs route. I can hit the rest service using SoapUi with a json object and get a response.

I wanted to write unit tests, and I though to use CamelTestSupport. My routebuilder configure() method looks something like this:

```
    from(cxfrsEndpoint)
        .recipientList(simple("direct:${header.operationName}"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_LENGTH, simple("-1"));

    from("direct:submitRequest")
        .bean("responseBean", "checkJson")
        .bean("responseBean", "createSuccessResponse");
```

When I hit the url from SoapUi (http://localhost:8181/cxf/myContext/submitRequest) as a POST with an appropriate json string, I get a "success" json back. Cool.

In my unit test, I created an overriden createRouteBuilder method:

```
@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {

    MyRouteBuilder myRouteBuilder = new MyRouteBuilder();
    myRouteBuilder.setCxfrsEndpoint("direct:start");
    return myRouteBuilder;
}
```

And then my unit test (I thought) would look something like this:

```
@Test
public void thisIsATest() throws Exception {

  MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest();
  request.setSomeProperty("Some property value");

  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String goodJsonRequest = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);

  String response = (String) template.requestBodyAndHeader(START_POINT, goodJsonRequest, "operationName", "submitRequest");
  assertNotNull(response);
  //Omitted: further assertions for content of the response json
}
```

Well, when I execute the unit test, I get an unmarshalling exception with this as the cause:

```
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
  at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
  at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:647)
  at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2054)
  at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1131)
  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:164)
  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:415)
... 74 more
```

It doesn't like my json string. What is the real service receiving?

On the real route, I enabled logging on the endpoint in the blueprint.xml like this:

```
<!-- RouteBuilder declarations -->
<bean id="myRouteBuilder" class="com.mycompany.MyRouteBuilder">
  <property name="cxfrsEndpoint"  value="cxfrs:bean:cxfrsEndpoint?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer&amp;loggingFeatureEnabled=true" />
</bean>
```

The json string I see in the log as the "Payload:" doesn't look any different than the json string I'm sending via template.requestBodyAndHeader(...).

What am I missing or what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me that your endpoint is expecting the payload coming as a XML request, not JSON. When you override the endpoint in `myRouteBuilder.setCxfrsEndpoint("direct:start");` you are changing how the route expects it.

Comment: If you need more details I may expose it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try not rewrite your endpoint like this:

`myRouteBuilder.setCxfrsEndpoint("direct:start");`

Seems to me that overriding your endpoint changes the interface and the CXF now is expecting a XML and not JSON (based on your logs):

```
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:647)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2054)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1131)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:164)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:415)
... 74 more
```

You already have the endpoint defined in here:

```
<bean id="myRouteBuilder" class="com.mycompany.MyRouteBuilder">
      <property name="cxfrsEndpoint"  value="cxfrs:bean:cxfrsEndpoint?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer&amp;loggingFeatureEnabled=true" />
</bean>
```

My suggestion is to use [this code](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-cxf/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/cxf/jaxrs/simplebinding/CxfRsConsumerSimpleBindingTest.java) as example and call your endpoint directly via HTTP:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
}

public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
    httpclient.close();
}

@Test
public void testGetCustomerOnlyHeaders() throws Exception {
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://serviceurl.com");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
}
```

If you have a chance, take a look into the entire [`camel-cxf`](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-cxf) project tests to have an idea how to properly test.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go and report back later today. Thanks for the reply.